# Integrate Switchtheme with Context?

Tags: 7

Im using Switchtheme to allow users to switch the theme of my site. Im also using Context and id like to create a new context depending on what theme has been chosen, but I cant see any options for this in the UI.

Comment: There is no integration between those two modules. There's no such context condition as "Current theme". If you need it urgently, you have to [write it yourself](http://dtek.net/blog/extending-drupals-context-module-custom-condition-based-field-value), or if you can wait then you can ask the module developer to do it, use the issue queue and choose "feature request".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, bit of searching and here you go: [Context Condition Theme](https://drupal.org/project/context_condition_theme)

> This module will add a conditional check within context for themes. Ever had the need to load a context based on which theme is being rendered?